# IBM Worklight - Handling push notifications in a Native Page

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am creating a Worklight-based Hybrid application with the Android environment.

My application has push notifications configured. It is currently able to process incoming notifications and display the message payload in a pop-up box.

I would like to do the same in the native portion of the hybrid app (native pages initiated using `WL.NativePage.show`).

However, I'm encountering some problems when trying to get the Push object to register the `registerEventSourceCallback` handler.

What am I doing wrong?

**Activity (Native page):**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WLClient client = WLClient.createInstance(this);
        WLPush push = client.getPush();  // throws exception here
        push.registerEventSourceCallback("myAndroid", "PushAdapter","PushEventSource", new PushNotificationListener() );
        ...
    }
```

**Exception:**

```
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.Marinet/com.Marinet.HelloNative}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@42648940
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2073)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2098)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:138)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1204)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Receiver not registered: com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver@42648940
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:654)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.ContextImpl.unregisterReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1211)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.unregisterReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:378)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(GCMRegistrar.java:266)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush.unregisterReceivers(WLPush.java:654)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLPush.<init>(WLPush.java:176)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at com.worklight.wlclient.api.WLClient.getPush(WLClient.java:673)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at com.Marinet.HelloNative.onCreate(HelloNative.java:53)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5244)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1082)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2037)
04-07 09:37:39.552: E/AndroidRuntime(6562):  ... 11 more
```

**Possible Solution:-**

```
public class GCMIntentService extends com.worklight.androidgap.push.GCMIntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!MyNativePage.isForeground()) { 
            // custom native page is not in foreground, handle it using existing WL methods
            super.onMessage(context, intent);
        } else {
            // custom native page is in foreground, skip existing WL method and use custom method
            MyNativePage.setNotificationMessage(intent.getExtras().getString("payload"));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worklight contains 2 push implementations. One is for Hybrid apps and another is for Native apps using the Worklight Native API.

The two *do not work together*. This means that you cannot receive a notification in the Hybrid app >> navigate to a native page using `WL.NativePage.show` >> and then use the Worklight Native API for push to handle the received payload.

What you can you, is receive the notification in the Hybrid app and pass along its payload as you load the native page.

Passing data from Hybrid to Native is explained and demoed in the following training module:

- [Using native pages in hybrid applications](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/06_04_Android_-_Using_native_pages_in_hybrid_applications.pdf)
- [Sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/AndroidApacheCordovaPluginProject.zip)

Comment: So that means the worklight hybrid app does not support push notification for native pages? Not even if the scenario is:- Start the hybrid >> navigate to a native page using WL.NativePage.show >> receive a notification and use the Worklight Native API for push to handle the received payload?

Comment: If You've like to perform actions on the payload of a notification in a WL.NativePage, transfer to data as shown in the documentation.

Comment: I was able to test out the approach you suggested by adding "WL.NativePage.show" in the "WL.Client.Push.registerEventSourceCallback" handler of the hybrid app. However, once the app is on the native page and another notification message comes in. Instead of being processed by the hybrid notification message handler, we find that the notification instead appears in the notification bar.

Comment: This is true. When in the web portion of the app, Worklight listens for incoming notifications and you are then able to capture the payload and display it via JS code. However, when you move to a *WL.NativePage*, there is no listener that will listen to incoming notifications. In current versions of Worklight what you can try to implement (register) a notification receiver that will listen to incoming notification and prase it.

Comment: Yes, that works. I'm able to receive and process the notification through a custom broadcast receiver registered with the activity. However, the notification still appears in the notification bar. I believe that's generated by worklight receiver registered by hybrid app. How can we refine that part?

Comment: In addition, when the user clicks on the notification on the notification bar. They will be brought back to the hybrid part of the app and reprocess notification again. Resulting in the same notification message being processed twice. Once by the hybrid app handler. Another by the custom handler registered by the native activity

Comment: So I think you need to dig deeper with the broadcast receiver you're implementing in Java because it should be possible to grab the payload and display it in the native portion And remove it from the notification bar. If you manage that, this will solve the problem of it appearing in the web portion I believe. Again, currently this is an unsupported scenario in Worklight, hence the need to do what you're doing now... Whether it works or not will depends on your implementation... Hopefully. I cannot guarantee anything.

Comment: Are we allowed to extend the GCMIntentService used by WL? If we customize the existing GCMIntentService.onMessage, we can actually prevent the message from appearing in the notification bar when the native page is active. What do you think? (see first post)

Comment: Sure you can do that, but we won't be able to support you if errors happen... If it works for you, all is good.

Comment: What is the equivalent action for iOS?